# perl: how do I read all lines from a file and print as one line of text

Tags: perl, string, file

I am trying to return the output of a file replacing newlines with \n without using CPAN

Here is what I have so far

```
#! /usr/local/bin/perl 

if ( $#ARGV = "1" )     {
    print "$ARGV[0]\n";

    my $file = "$ARGV[0]";
    my $document = do {
        local $/;
        open my $fh, "<", $file
          or die "could not open $file: $!";
        <$fh>;
    };
    print "Doc: $document\n";
}
```

Comment: Newlines *are* `\n`.. unless you're on one of those crazy systems.

Comment: Do you really want a literal backslash followed by an n? Why would you want that?

Comment: Let's say it all together now: turn on warnings!  Either with a -w at the end of the #! line or `use warnings` in the code.  That will reveal an important problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the slurp mode (no more need for a while loop) and some regexp :

```
print map { $_ =~ s/\n/\\n/; $_ } (<>);
```

Or some special variables :

```
my @a = <>;
$\ = $, = '\n';
chomp @a;
print @a;
```

($\ is the output record separator, and $, is the output field separator. Both apply to the print operator)

Answer (score 3):

```
while(<>) {chomp;print;print '\n';}
```

Comment: `print '\n'` will not do what you expect. (Try it and see.)

Comment: @Ether: It does exactly what I expect. The intent is to print a backslash followed by an "n", *not* a newline.

Comment: Hmm ok, I completely misinterpreted what the OP wanted then. :)  To be less ambiguous, you could say `'\\n'` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this ...

```
#! /usr/bin/perl 

if ( $#ARGV = "1" )     {
open FILE, "<", "$ARGV[0]" or die $!;
chomp $_;
@chars = map ({ $_ =~ s/\n/\\n/; $_ } (<FILE>)); 
print @chars;
print "@chars\n";
}
```

.. and it gives me the right output (except for some spaces that I need to learn how to strip out)

Comment: And what appens when you run your script without any arguments ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a long solution for clarity. In a nutshell, chomp will drop all trailing whitespace and control characters.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = shift;
my @contents;
my $lines = 0;

if (! -e $filename) {
    print "Please provide a valid filename\n";
    exit;
}

print "Examining $filename\n";

open(FILE, "<$filename");

while (<FILE>) {
    chomp();
    push(@contents, $_);
    print ".";  
    $lines++;
    if ($lines % 10 == 0) {
        print "\n";
    }
}
close(FILE);

print "done\n";

foreach (@contents) {
    print "$_";
}

print "\n";
```